# Meaning of project files icons in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, projects-and-solutions

In Android Studio, in the Project list of files, what is the difference between these 2 icons :

[image]

and also between these 2 icons :

[image]

Thank you

Comment: You can atleast add details like what version of Android Studio you are using

Comment: The last one (stable)